# How to call a function that is in return of another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql-codegen

I am trying to access a function called in return of another function, but when I access it normally I get the error:

```
TypeError: adminSdk.InsertGameAuthRefreshTokens is not a function
    at insertGameAuthRefreshTokens (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\.next\server\pages\api\gameAuthCallback.js:1496:20)
    at handler (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\.next\server\pages\api\gameAuthCallback.js:1434:26)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Object.apiResolver (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils.js:114:13)
    at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:763:9)
    at async Object.fn (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:654:37)
    at async Router.execute (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:206:32)
    at async DevServer.run (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:831:29)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\Projects\CHRIS\vsm-nft-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:295:20)
```

Here's the function that I want to acess **(funcName)**

```
  const adminSdk = getAdminSdk({
    endpoint,
    adminSecret,
  })

  return {
    async funcName(data) {
      const { graphql_mutation_name: response } = adminSdk.generatedFuncName({ data })

      return {
        userId: response.user_id,
      }
    },
  }
}
```

and here's how I am calling the function

```
const sdk = HasuraAdapter(args)
const { funcName} = sdk
  const response = await funcName(data)
  console.log(response)
```

Anyone who can help me on how to access that function in return{} statement?

Comment: You run this function correctly. It's something else that is not working

Comment: If you console log "sdk" and "HasuraAdapter(args)", does it show anything relating to a child function?

Comment: Yes, when I console log sdk it shows me that there's a function with the value [AsyncFunction: generatedFuncName]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the function isn't being recognized in the return, or sdk isn't being recognized having that function member. Console log to double check "sdk" and "HasuraAdapter(args)" actually have a function attached. Generally, to call a function in the return of a function, you would do something like this:

[image: Example generic solution]

Comment: Seems like the problem is from the ```adminSdk.generatedFuncName``` it is what the compiler is claiming to not be a function